# How to make player move forward by it's own in Unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made player movement script. By that you can move player with mouse/finger to left/right and I want to add code that will make player move forward on it's own on start. So basically like platform runner. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour{
    
    private SwerveInputSystem _swerveInputSystem;
    [SerializeField] private float swerveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxSwerveAmount = 1f;

    void Start(){

        _swerveInputSystem = GetComponent<SwerveInputSystem>();
    }


    void Update(){
        float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * _swerveInputSystem.MoveFactorX;
        swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);
        transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a `verticalSpeed` variable and include that in your `Translate()` call.

```
// You can, of course, call this whatever you'd like.
[SerializeField] private float verticalSpeed;

void Update(){
    float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * _swerveInputSystem.MoveFactorX;
    swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);
    float verticalDelta = verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Plug verticalDelta into Translate(). Whether you use it in the y or z component depends on your game.
    transform.Translate(swerveAmount, verticalDelta, 0);
}
```